# Does Atlassian Confluence have local documentation for non-Internet installs

Tags: offline, wiki, confluence

I've installed Confluence as a wiki on my local network.

The network doesn't have Internet access.

There are lots of locations in the Confluence admin and demonstration space where links to Internet content are provided (particularly for guidance).

Is there a way to replace this Internet guidance with locally installed shapshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

Atlassian provide an XML backup of the documentation site that you can restore into your Wiki.  You then change the help prefix to use a local URL instead of the Atlassian one.  But, the current (4.1.5) copy of Confluence doesn't have this config parameter where the documentation says it is.

Here are the steps:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Local+Confluence+Documentation

Note, I couldn't get the zip to restore, it was failing on some kind of icon not found error.

Atlassian do also provide an Html Zip of the help - so I may just try to serve it locally instead of imported into the wiki, though I'd lose the ability to search or edit it. There again, I'll still struggle from the missing help-prefix config setting.